# Single column values ends up in multi dimension array

Tags: excel, vba

I am populating a array with values from part of a column (range). The resulting array is multidimensional - but it should be one dimensional. I want to get just `Emp ID` values into the array:

[image]

I have tried this :

```
Sub Test()

Dim colPostionNumber As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim positionNumberArray As Variant

Set ws = ActiveSheet

With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 1")
    colPositionNumber = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Emp ID", ws.Rows(5), 0)
    lastRow = ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row

positionNumberArray = .Range(Cells(5, colPositionNumber), Cells(lastRow, colPositionNumber)).Value

End With

End Sub
```

But the resulting array is two dimensional

[image]

I tried reDim but that didn't work. How do I do this with a one dimensional array?

Comment: Reading a multi-cell contiguous range into an array always gives you a 2D 1-based array.  There's no way to change that, but you could write a function which gives you a 1D array from a single row/column of cells.

Answer (score 1):

### Write One-Column 2D Array to 1D Array

To get a zero-based 1D array, you will have to loop.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim colPositionNumber As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Data As Variant
    Dim positionNumberArray As Variant
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 1")
        colPositionNumber = Application.Match("Emp ID", ws.Rows(5), 0)
        lastRow = ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
        Data = .Range(.Cells(5, colPositionNumber), _
            .Cells(lastRow, colPositionNumber)).Value
        ReDim positionNumberArray(UBound(Data, 1) - 1)
        Dim n As Long
        For n = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
            positionNumberArray(n - 1) = Data(n, 1)
        Next n
    End With

End Sub
```

### Using Application.Transpose

The following procedures show how to write a one-column or a one-row range to a one-based 1D array:

```
Sub testATColumn()
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Range("A1:A5")
    Dim arr As Variant: arr = Application.Transpose(rg.Value)
    Debug.Print LBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 1)
    On Error Resume Next
    Debug.Print LBound(arr, 2), UBound(arr, 2)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Sub testATRow()
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Range("A1:E1")
    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(rg.Value))
    Debug.Print LBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 1)
    On Error Resume Next
    Debug.Print LBound(arr, 2), UBound(arr, 2)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Note that `Application.Transpose` has a limit of 65535 elements per dimension.

Comment: So it is not possible to get the range into variant one dimensional? Does it always create two dimensional?

Comment: PS: Position number should be Emp ID

Comment: You could do `positionNumberArray = Application.Transpose(.Range(.Cells(5, colPositionNumber), _
            .Cells(lastRow, colPositionNumber)).Value)` which will result in a **one-based** 1D array. Its (`Transpose`) limitation is `65535` elements and there are some problems with dates.

Answer (score 1):

**Reduce dimension via Excel function `ArrayToText()`**

If you dispose of *version MS 365* you could try the following approach via Excel function `ArrayToText()` and an eventual split action.

```
Sub reduceDim()
    Dim t#: t = Timer
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sheet1.Range("B2:B7")            ' << change to your needs
    Dim data
    data = Split(Evaluate("ArrayToText(" & rng.Address(False, False, External:=True) & ")"), ", ")

    Debug.Print "Array(" & LBound(data) & " To " & UBound(data) & ")"
    Debug.Print Join(data, "|")                 ' display resulting 0-based 1-dim array elements

    Debug.Print Format(Timer - t, "0.00 secs")
End Sub
```

**Output in VB Editor's immediate window**

```
    Array(0 To 5)
    1|2|3|4|5|6
    0,00 secs
```

Comment: Greetings, `Dr. Evaluate`. Well done, as always.